# Connecting app to ParseServer on Heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, parse-server

I am following those tutorials:
http://rogerstringer.com/2016/02/04/parse-server-heroku/
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku

I am trying to deploy a ParseServer to Heroku and connect my app with it.
The part with deploying is going just ok, I can see this one:
'I dream of being a web site.'

I don't know where to put clientId, and appId. 
Those are my config vars from Heroku part:

[image: Heroku config vars]

Here is the code in ParseServer, that I have on github:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'reciparia',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '' //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
});
```

And code in AppDelegate:

```
   let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
  ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "reciparia"
  ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
  ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://amazing-parse.herokuapp.com/parse"
})
```

Since it's mandatory to have a clientKey on `ParseClientConfiguration`, I should have one on the ParseServer.

Where should I put it? On Config Vars from Heroku UI, or index.js from ParseServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `clientKey` needs to be on `ParseServer` (located on `index.js`) and on AppDelegate.swift (on client side).

I added `clientKey` to `index.js` from ParseServer. Variable `appId` needs also to be found in both sides:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'reciparia',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY || 'holla'
});
```

AppDelegate.swift, stays the same:

```
  let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {   (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
     ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "reciparia"
     ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "holla"
     ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://amazing-parse.herokuapp.com/parse"
  })
```

I also modified config vars a little bit, for having the same CLIENT_KEY and APP_ID here too. I find it more convenient to modify now just config vars and AppDelegate since my credentials are public now :).

[image: configs]